# NodeJS package dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

I have defined a NPM package with the following dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "kwire": "0.0.1"
  }
```

I then create a new project folder with a `node_modules` folder in the root and a `package.json`, and run `npm install --save my-package`.

I end up with `my-package` being placed in `node_modules`, and all its dependencies being placed in an inner `node_modules` folder, within the `my-package` folder.

This all seems normal.

When I fire up a Node.js REPL from the `my-project` folder and write:

```
var m = require('my-package');
```

It results in an error `kwire` is not defined.

It is falling over on a line like this inside `my-package`:

```
require('kwire');
```

What do I need to do to ensure that `my-package` can see `kwire`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `"files": []` inside your `package.json` file. My typical workflow is to structure my `package.json` as :

```
"dependencies": {
    "package1": "latest",
    "package2": "latest"
    ...
},
"files": [
    "index.js",
    "lib/"
]
```

Inside `index.js` I prefer passing my dependencies from the `lib/` folder as:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = require('./lib/bootstrap');
```

And into /lib/bootstrap.js I can start injecting a module as:

```
var test = require('package1');
```

Or a local dependency as:

```
var Router = require('./router');
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) is also a useful gist explaining module dependencies.